# Maven dependencies lister for SVN repository

Tags: gratis, software-development, command-line

I'm looking for a free **command line tool** (Windows or Linux), that

1. walks a given **SVN repository**,
2. processes all Maven **pom.xml** files,
3. collects all **dependencies** (optional: recursive) and
4. creates some form of tabular output, listing:

   - **groupId**
   - **artifactId**
   - **version**

I'd be glad about a short how-to for the given use case.

Comment: write script for this, use maven:dependency plugin...